# javafx: What is the fastest way to move all elements from one observablelist to another?

Tags: java, javafx

I have an observableList `ol1` which contains many `Person` objects and I want to transfer all items from this list to another observableList `ol2`. Apart from using for loop / for-each loop , is there any other method that is quick and easy ?

I tried `ol1.addAll(ol2)` but this fails.

**Update:**
Apologies. I have managed to find out that there is actually a bug in my code and I was able to resolve my original problem using `ol1.addAll(ol2)`. Truly appreciated your comments and answers. I will never post without formulating my problem properly going forward. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see what's hard about using a for-each, but did you tried using the method addAll?

Comment: Note that the bulk methods (such as `addAll`, `setAll`, and `clear`) will (at least potentially) fire fewer notifications to observers than using a loop.

Comment: I tried `addAll` but it failed.

Comment: Then you need to be specific.

Comment: I can't repeat it often enough: Please provide always an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Every other attempt is like to solve a riddle with a NP-hard problem space.

Comment: Sorry about this. I will think how I can create a MCVE of my problem and repost again. Apologies

Comment: Well, at least explain how the "ol1.addAll(ol2) but this fails." Exception? Wrong result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is faster, but you could use:

```
ObservableList<Person> ol2 = FXCollections.observableList(ol1);
```

Comment: The functionality of that is different though: you're creating a new list backed by the old one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [setAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ObservableList.html#setAll-java.util.Collection-) or [addAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ObservableList.html#addAll-E...-).